# Получить список серверов по TCP

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-xe8

Пытаюсь получить список серверов

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Host := '163.158.182.243';
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 28900;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Socket.Write('001');
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings(Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

Дальше этого места выполнение кода не происходит

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings(Memo1.Lines);
```

Получаю всё, но программа повисает намертво. Где допущена ошибка?
Повисало из-за того, что в

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings
```

не указывалось **AReadLinesCount: Integer**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write('001');
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings(Memo1.Lines, [COLOR="Red"]25[/COLOR], IndyTextEncoding(IdTextEncodingType.encOSDefault));

  Panel1.Caption := 'Всего строк: ' + IntToStr(Memo1.Lines.Count);
end;
```

Как узнать **AReadLinesCount** при получении ответа?

Comment: Вы показали только клиентскую часть, которая практически ничего не говорит. Уточните какой протокол вы используете. Почитайте спецификацию вашего протокола. TCP-протокол нижнего уровня, он не обладает достаточно-определёнными правилами что б узнать где у вас ошибка. А у вас ошибка - нарушение обмена по протоколу верхнего уровня.

Comment: Серверная часть не у меня. Сниффером проанализировал, как этот список получает другая программа и захотел реализовать тоже самое.

Comment: Посмотрите снифером в heх-представлении (если его нету - поменяйте снифер). Скорее всего у вас тут `IdTCPClient1.Socket.Write('001');` отсутствует возврат каретки (их бывает два вида `#13` и `#10#13`) или другой "опознавательный байт". То что виснет - она не виснет, это означает вы не правильные байты передали

Comment: 00000000  30 30 31                                           001 - чужая прога
00000000  30 30 31                                           001 - моя прога. Одинвково

Comment: Читайте с сокета ответ по одному байту, вместо `ReadStrings`, ReadStrings вам не подходит.